# How do I target an object inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've got the following array in php:

```
$myarray = array(
            array('normaal' => _("Normale versie"),'extra' => "Wel rillen"),
            array('aangepast' => _("De aangepaste versie"),'extra' => "Niet rillen")
         );
```

I'm trying to get the following output in HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    Normale versie
    <br>
    Wel rillen
</div>
<div class="container">
    De aangepaste versie
    <br>
    Niet rillen
</div>
```

I tried looping the array with a foreach loop like so:

```
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo $value[0];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $value['extra'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Hoping the `$value[0]` would target the value of the first object in the array. This targets the entire object however and thus returns nothing. Resulting in the following faulty output:

```
<div class="container">

    <br>
    Wel rillen
</div>
<div class="container">

    <br>
    Niet rillen
</div>
```

I somehow need to target the first arrayitem by it's object name, this object name is different for every array item, how do I go about targeting it's content without knowing what the object name is going to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your case, use [key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) to get name of key, as:

```
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo $value[key($value)];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $value['extra'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an associative array, not indexed. So your array actually does not contain "0" element. But you can get first element of nested array by calling `first()` function.
You code will look like this:

```
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo first($value);
    echo '<br>';
    echo $value['extra'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a TWO-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY.

the first [] is the location of the array object and the second [] is the location of the item in the oject's array.

```
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo $value[0][0];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $value[0]['extra'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo first($value);
    echo '<br>';
    echo $value['extra'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myarray = array(
    array('normaal' => "Normale versie", 'extra' => "Wel rillen"),
    array('aangepast' => "De aangepaste versie", 'extra' => "Niet rillen")
);
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    echo '<div class="container">';
    reset($value);
    echo $value[key($value)];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $value['extra'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```